# HTML open URL from a href data attribute

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML.
I've following code piece:

```
<a href="#B" id="specialClass" class="primary-btn icon-cart" data-one="#A" data-five="google.com" data-ten="#C" target="_blank">
    <span id="pressButton">New Button</span>
</a>
```

When I press button based on slider and data-five gets triggered, I for some reason open in a new tab `mywebsite.com/google.com` instead of `google.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please also include whatever JS is handling your data attributes. As is, the link should send you to `mywebsite.com#B`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an address outside your web page you have to put the full path with https://google.es
`<a target="_blank" href="https://google.es">Google</a>`

Comment: Thanks, that was silly from my side, lol.